# Ending a game in Unity - Alphabet Game

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am new to programming and I have followed a video on how to create an Alphabet game in unity which displays a letter on the screen, when 5 of those letters are selected it moves onto the next letter.
The issue that I am facing is that game continues on with various characters after the letter Z.

How can I get my game to end once the player has completed the letter Z rather than continuing to other characters?

Here's my code below:

Game Controller:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour
{

    public char Letter = 'a';
    
    int _correctAnswers = 5;
    int _correctClicks;
    

    void OnEnable()
    {
        GenerateBoard();
        UpdateDiplayLetters();
    }

    void GenerateBoard()
    {
        var clickables = FindObjectsOfType<ClickableLetter>();

        List<char> charsList = new List<char>();

        for (int i = 0; i < _correctAnswers; i++)
            charsList.Add(Letter);

        for (int i = _correctAnswers; i < clickables.Length; i++)
        {
            var chosenLetter = ChooseInvalidRandomLetter();
            charsList.Add(chosenLetter);
        }

        charsList = charsList
            .OrderBy(t => UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 10000))
            .ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < clickables.Length; i++)
        {
            clickables[i].SetLetter(charsList[i]);
        }

        FindObjectOfType<RemainingCounterText>().SetRemaining(_correctAnswers - _correctClicks);
    }

    internal void HandleCorrectLetterClick(bool upperCase)
    {

        _correctClicks++;
        FindObjectOfType<RemainingCounterText>().SetRemaining(_correctAnswers - _correctClicks);
        if (_correctClicks >= _correctAnswers)
        {
            Letter++;
            UpdateDiplayLetters();
            _correctClicks = 0;
            GenerateBoard();
        }
    }


    private void UpdateDiplayLetters()
    {
        foreach (var displayletter in FindObjectsOfType<DisplayLetter>())
        {
            displayletter.SetLetter(Letter);
        }
    }

    private char ChooseInvalidRandomLetter()
    {
        int a = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 26);
        var randomLetter = (char)('a' + a);
        while (randomLetter == Letter)
        {
            a = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 26);
            randomLetter = (char)('a' + a);
        }
        return randomLetter;
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right you could just when `Letter = 'z'` restart the scene or move to another scene where it says "you finished the game you can close the game now" or just disable everything in the scene beside the end game text or something like that.

I hope this answer is useful and good luck.